# 2D array concatenation in fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

Fortran 2003 has square bracket syntax for array concatenation, Intel fortran compiler supports it too. I wrote a simple code here for matrix concatenation:

```
program matrix
implicit none
real,dimension (3,3) :: mat1,mat2
real,dimension(3,6):: mat3
integer i

mat1=reshape( (/1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9/),(/3,3/))
mat2=reshape( (/1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9/),(/3,3/))
mat3=[mat1,mat2]

!display
do i=1,3,1
write(*,10) mat3(i,:)
10 format(F10.4)
end do

end program
```

But I get error as

```
mat3=[mat1,mat2]
Error: Incompatible ranks 2 and 1 in assignment
```

I expect the output as

```
1 2 3 1 2 3
4 5 6 4 5 6
7 8 9 7 8 9
```

Can someone comment where am I going wrong? What is rank 2 and 1 here? I guess all arrays have rank 2.

Comment: *Fortran 2003 has square bracket syntax for array concatenation*  I wouldn't put it that way.  Fortran 2003 offers square brackets as an alternative to the long-established `(/` and `/)` for delimiting an array, as illustrated in the two uses of `reshape` in the code.  The way you write suggests you might think that the square brackets are some kind of operator; they're not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The array concatenation in fortran 2003 doesn't work as you think. When you concatenate, it's not going to stack the two arrays side by side. It will pick elements from the first array one by one and put into a one-dimensional array. Then it will do the same thing with the second array but it will append this to the 1-D form of first array.

The following code works.

```
program matrix
implicit none
real,dimension (3,3) :: mat1,mat2
real,dimension(18) :: mat3
integer i

mat1=reshape( (/1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9/),(/3,3/))
mat2=reshape( (/1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9/),(/3,3/))
mat3=[mat1,mat2]

print*, shape([mat1,mat2])  !check shape of concatenated array
!display
do i=1,18,1
write(*,10) mat3(i)
10 format(F10.4)
end do

end program
```

However, the result you wanted can be achieved using following code

```
program matrix
implicit none
real,dimension (3,3) :: mat1,mat2
real,dimension(3,6) :: mat3
integer i

mat1=reshape( (/1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9/),(/3,3/))
mat2=reshape( (/1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9/),(/3,3/))

do i=1,3
mat3(i,:)=[mat1(:,i),mat2(:,i)]
enddo

!display
do i=1,3,1
write(*,*) mat3(i,:)
end do

end program
```

Comment: You will get trailing zeroes with all the numbers because you have declared the matrix as real. I noticed you expected only integer. Declaring array as integer will fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Another way could simply be to

```
mat3(:,1:3) = mat1
mat3(:,4:6) = mat2
```

I dont know which is faster, this or the do loop above...

Answer (score -1):

Fill it using 1-D arrays then reshape your mat3.